# How do I check if one number contains itself in any order?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to do something where I have two numbers (let's say 123 and 321). And I want to check if the first number has the same digits as the second in any order. I know how to do this if I check for the 1, the 2, and the 3 individually, but I want to check the entire integer. In other words, I need a code that says "if number *x* has the same digits as number *y* (in any order), then..."
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Split both of the strings into a list of integers, sort the lists and then compare them.

Comment: What do you want to happen if either of the numbers are negative?

Comment: @sprinter I actually haven't thought about that. Because I'm trying to make a small betting game, so the numbers won't be negative. So it'll say "if you bet on the number 123 and the winning number is 123 you win $600 (as an example). If you bet on 123 and the winning number is 231 you win $200 (because you got the same numbers but in the wrong order). And if you bet on 123 and the number is 586, then you lose." If the numbers are negative, I'll probably make it say "That's not a valid betting or winning number".

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the Java syntax but convert each number to an array.  Sort the arrays ascending.  Convert back to a number and compare.

If you don't want an exact match (i.e. 112233 and 123 both share the same digits), then walk through 1 array and see if each digit is contained in the other.

Answer (score 1):

This code will turn both integers into strings and then check to see if the strings are the same length and the second string contains all of the characters of the first.

```
public class Sandbox { //opens class

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 125;
        int y = 321;
        boolean hasNumbers = true;
        String a = Integer.toString(x);
        String b = Integer.toString(y);

        if(a.length() == b.length()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {

                if(!b.contains(String.valueOf(a.charAt(i)))) {
                    hasNumbers = false;
                }
            }
            if(hasNumbers) {
                System.out.println(x + " contains the digits of " + y);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(x + " does not contain the digits of " + y);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The length of " + x + " and " + y + " are different");
        }   
    }   
}
```

You could definitely tidy it up quite a bit but I believe it solves the problem you stated.

Comment: The complexity of this algorithm is O(n2), since b.contains is a O(n) operation. I think it can be done in O(n).

Comment: Where exactly did the OP say that the algorithm needed to be O(n)?

Comment: I am not saying the OP asks for an O(n) algorithm, but the faster the better, isn't is? :P

Comment: Not always. If you're comparing 2 numbers then there is no advantage to having a faster algorithm. None. In this case, I wrote an algorithm that I believed was easy to understand, since if someone is asking this question they probably need. Do you think this person will know what a HashSet is or what O(n) is? They just want an answer to their question that they can understand and learn from. If this problem was real life then speed still wouldn't matter, unless it was faster to write it another way. The suggestions that suggested arrays were the best. I just felt strings were easier to grasp.

Comment: I'll grant you that speed would matter if the number were enormous. Several hundred digits, for example. But I don't think this person is going to have that kind of number. Do you?

Comment: I'll go further than @ChrisSharp answer. Faster is almost never better. Clearer is almost always better. Optimising code that doesn't need to be optimised is a very common mistake.

Comment: @sprinter, ChrisSharp Clearly your answer is correct, I am just trying to make it faster. Of course you are right, that the complexity only matters if the numbers are huge. In fact, if we use the type int here, it can not be that huge. I just want to give a different idea to solve this problem and it happens to be O(n). I don't think there is any issue with the clarity of my algorithm, it only stores all the digits appearing in "a" in a set and checks if there is any that doesn't exist in "b". HashSet just makes it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : The basic idea : The algorithm simply stores all the digits appearing in "a" in a set and checks if there is any that doesn't exist in "b".

Here is some code for implementing this logic. It basically makes use of the fact, that Set doesn't contain duplicate elements. HashSet can perform add, contains in a constant time, plus the maximum size of the digits set is 10, the function can be executed in O(n).

```
public boolean checkSameDigits(int x, int y){
   String a = Integer.toString(x);
   String b = Integer.toString(y);

   Set digits = new HashSet();
   for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
       digits.add(a.charAt(i));
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
       if(!digits.contains(b.charAt(i)))
           return false; 
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert each number to a sorted list of digits then you can just compare the two lists:

```
private List<Integer> sortedDigits(int number, int base) {
    assert number >= 0 && base > 0;
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int n = number; n > 0; n /= base)
        digits.add(n % base);
    digits.sort();
    return digits;
}
```

So then `sortedDigits(number1, 10).equals(sortedDigits(number2, 10))` will check if the digits are the same in base 10.

Answer (score 0):

A rather short implementation is to get a `char[]` for each, sort, and check if they're the same:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Whatever {
    public static final boolean sameDigits(final int m, final int n) {
         final char[] m2 = ("" + m).toCharArray();
         final char[] n2 = ("" + n).toCharArray();
         Arrays.sort(m2);
         Arrays.sort(n2);
         return Arrays.equals(m2, n2);
    }
}
```